# No value for key "javax.xml.ws.wsdl.service" on org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage with camel version 3.17.0 and cxf 3.5.5

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf, spring-camel, camel-cxf

In my legacy project I had to upgrade camel dependency org.apache.camel.springboot::**camel-spring-boot-bom** from version 3.7.4 to 3.17.0 and org.apache.cxf::**cxf-bom** from version 3.4.2 to 3.5.5.

With the versions 3.7.4 for camel and 3.4.2 for cxf I got the `QName` with following few lines:

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.camel.component.cxf.common.message.CxfConstants;

final Map<String, Object> messageHeaders = exchange.getIn().getHeaders();
SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) messageHeaders.get(CxfConstants.CAMEL_CXF_MESSAGE);
QName serviceName = QName.valueOf(soapMessage.get(Message.WSDL_SERVICE).toString());
```

with the newer versions camel 3.17.0 and cxf 3.5.5 I had to rewrite it to following

```
final  Map<String, Object> jaxwsContextProperties = (Map<String, Object>) exchange.getProperties().get(CxfConstants.JAXWS_CONTEXT);
 QName serviceName = (QName) jaxwsContextProperties.get(Message.WSDL_SERVICE);
```

I couldn't find those changes or related ones in any release notes. Every hint where on the way this got changed is very much appreciated! Thanks a lot!